# Get Employee Code for the Pick, Pack and Ship Screen

Tags: acumatica, erp

Custom field should auto-populate with Employee code (3-digit for the Warehouse team) of the person logged-in and cannot be changed manually. Name should be displayed next to the code field.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please add your code and the issue that you have

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov I was able to add the above field and solve the issue.

Do you have any idea about this other problem I am facing.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72498448/not-able-to-customize-lead-screen-source-dropdown